# Changing Times into Standard Datetime Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I'm currently working with a dataset which has a Time variable, however, the times are stored rather oddly. They are stored like:

```
42:49.0
42:49.0
42:49.1
42:49.1
42:49.2
42:49.2
42:49.3
42:49.3
...
...
42:49.9
42:49.9
42:50.0
42:50.0
```

The times are currently formatted as MM:SS.s where MM is the current minute and SS is the current second. The measurements are taken twenty times every second (20 Hz), so that is presumably what the decimal place is describing. However, it would make more sense if the decimal place was either a measure of milliseconds, or in a predictable pattern such as `.00, .01, .02, ..., .19, .20`.

There are a few problems I've encountered. First, there is no "Hour" section in my time. Secondly, I'd like to convert these times into the following format `HH:MM:SS:sss`, where sss is the millisecond measurement. The hour can start at `00` or `12`, it doesn't really matter. Then, I'd like to somehow add on a millisecond measurement which would be either `00` or `50`.

Also, some of the measurements are actually 21 Hz or 19 Hz, so there are 21 or 19 measurements of time each second. So the milliseconds unit would be different, and needs to accommodate those specific cases.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tinkered around with the `datetime` package in Python hoping that something would help, but but the decimal point is what's messing me up.

Any thoughts on what to do here?

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: What object type are your time variables? Can you supply us with some example code to reproduce?